# How do I add this .sty to my document

Tags: packages, texmaker, logic

So I have been trying to add this .sty file to my texmaker
http://www.actual.world/resources/tex/sty/ND.sty, but I have no idea what to do with this link?
Should I just copy and paste the text into a .txt file then change the file type or do I have to copy and paste this text into a different file?

Sorry if this seems dumb, I'm just genuinely confused about what to do with this and I have not been able to find anything online to help me.

Comment: Drop it into your folder and then `usepackage{ND}` to use it in your main file.

Comment: You shouldn't need to copy and paste text.  Just right click and select "Save link as ..." and don't change the name.  Save it in the same directory as your main tex file.